# FLUTTER - Android Clearing data or cache another application in my own application

Tags: flutter, directory, flutter-dependencies

i have some problem when develop my application using flutter.

So i have my application flow like this

1. User login to my application
2. There is dashboard after login showing some apps like (YouTube, Netflix, Instagram, Twitter, etc)
3. If user click the logo of app, the app will be open.
4. If my user clicking logout from ... (Example "Logout from YouTube") then my app can automate proccess for log out from YouTube.

I achieve step 2 and 3 using library [device_apps](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps)

I search arround google and cant find the right answer to do this.
I already tried to get the path of app package like /data/user/0/com.google.android.youtube and the delete it but return existSync() always false

```
logoutYt() async {
    String packageNameYT = "com.google.android.youtube";
    var app = await DeviceApps.getApp(packageNameYT, true);
    if (app != null) {
      // app.openSettingsScreen();
      bool isInstalled = await DeviceApps.isAppInstalled(packageNameYT);
      if (isInstalled) {
        var dirYt = Directory(app.dataDir ?? '');
        if (dirYt.existsSync()) {
          dirYt.deleteSync();
        }
        // DeviceApps.uninstallApp(packageNameYT);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is what i tried before, and the output was always false

```
I/flutter (11529): Directory: '/data/user/0/com.google.android.youtube'
I/flutter (11529): false
```

Please tell me an answer or solution to make this possible. Thanks